# Keep Docker intermediate layers in multistage build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm attempting to have a dev container and a "production" container built from a single `Dockerfile`, it already "works" but I do not have access to the dev container after the build (multistage intermediaries are cached, but not tagged in a useful way).

The `Dockerfile` is as-so:

```
# See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3649 why here
# is a separate one for a flow using image ... :(
FROM node:8.9.4-slim AS graphql-dev
WORKDIR /graphql-api
ENV PATH /graphql-api/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN apt update && apt install -y libelf1
ADD ./.babelrc /graphql-api/
ADD ./.eslintignore /graphql-api/
ADD ./.eslintrc /graphql-api/
ADD ./.flowconfig /graphql-api/
ADD ./.npmrc /graphql-api/
ADD ./*.json5 /graphql-api/
ADD ./lib/ /graphql-api/lib
ADD ./package.json /graphql-api/
ADD ./schema/ /graphql-api/schema
ADD ./yarn.lock /graphql-api/
RUN yarn install --production --silent && npm install --silent
CMD ["npm", "run", "lint-flow-test"]

# Cleans node_modules etc, see github.com/tj/node-prune
# this container contains no node, etc (golang:latest)
FROM golang:latest AS graphql-cleaner
WORKDIR /graphql-api
ENV PATH /graphql-api/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY --from=graphql-dev graphql-api .
RUN go get github.com/tj/node-prune/cmd/node-prune
RUN node-prune

# Minimal end-container (Alpine )
FROM node:8.9.4-alpine
WORKDIR /graphql-api
ENV PATH /graphql-api/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY --from=graphql-cleaner graphql-api .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Ideally I'd be able to start `graphql-dev` and the final container both with a `docker-compose.yml`, as so:

```
version: '3'
services:
  graphql-dev:
    image: graphql-dev
    build: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./lib:/graphql-api/lib
      - ./schema:/graphql-api/schema
  graphql-prod:
    image: graphql
    build: ./Dockerfile
```

The two final steps are the "shrinking" for the final build (saves over 250Mb for us) are not really required except for in the production build.

- If I extract the dockerfile into two.. somehow `Dockerfile.prod` and `Dockerfile.dev` then I have to manage dependencies between them as I can't force `prod` to always build `dev` (can I?)
- If I were somehow able to specify `target` on the build in the docker-compose.yml file I could do it, there were some issues, but specifying a `target` under `build` in my yml file yields an error:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>     services.graphql-dev.build contains unsupported option: 'target'

Comment: are you specifying a version in your docker-compose file?

Comment: I am, yes version 3, actually (which actually is required, v2 doesn't support the `build.context:` parameter at all)

Comment: Try "3.2" for the version